Why does webpack conditionally exclude certain modules with potential side effects from the bundle?
I have two pieces of code that look almost identical, but when I build them with webpack, I notice a key difference in the resulting bundles.
In one case, the module is included in the bundle, while in the other case, it is excluded.
I expected that webpack would include all modules with potential side effects in the bundle, regardless of any conditional logic.
However, it seems this isn’t always the case. Could anyone explain why this difference occurs?

Case where the module is included in the bundle

// index.js
const flag = false;
if (flag) {
  require("./myModule");
}

// dist/bundle.js
(() => {
  var e = {
      584: (e, r, t) => {
        "use strict";
        function o() {
          return "myFunction";
        }
        t.r(r), t.d(r, {myFunction: () => o});
      },
    },
    r = {};
  function t(o) {
    var n = r[o];
    if (void 0 !== n) return n.exports;
    var i = (r[o] = {exports: {}});
    return e[o](i, i.exports, t), i.exports;
  }
  (t.d = (e, r) => {
    for (var o in r)
      t.o(r, o) &&
        !t.o(e, o) &&
        Object.defineProperty(e, o, {enumerable: !0, get: r[o]});
  }),
    (t.o = (e, r) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r)),
    (t.r = (e) => {
      "undefined" != typeof Symbol &&
        Symbol.toStringTag &&
        Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {value: "Module"}),
        Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {value: !0});
    });
})();


Case where the module is excluded from the bundle

// index.js
if (false) {
  require("./myModule");
}

// dist/bundle.js
// It became an empty file.

example
myProject
├── src
│   ├── index.js
│   └── myModule.js
├── dist
├── webpack.config.js
└── package.json

// webpack.config.js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production", 
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true,
  },
};


// package.json
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.95.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}

// index.js
const flag = false;
if (flag) { // or if (false)
  require("./myModule");
}

// myModule.js
export function myFunction() {
  return "myFunction";
}


I can't reproduce it. In both cases, the side effects aren't triggered: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pv1xpw Can you provide a [mcve]? If you only mean the tree shaking, it's probably because Webpack is smart enough to detect, that if (false) {...} contains dead code, but const flag = false; if (flag) { ... } could be triggered using a debugger and manually changing the flag.

@jabaa Thank you for your comment. I have added a minimal example.

Is your question answered? In the second case, the code can be triggered and in first case, it's dead code.

@jabaa I didn’t fully understand your initial comment. The question is why the bundling result differs when a variable (set to false) is used in the if statement versus when false is directly inserted.

Beause in the case if (false) { ... } and the tree shaker sees it. In the other case, either the bundler doesn't see it or it's intended because you can change the value of flag using your debugger. What exactly do you not understand or what is still unclear?

@jabaa After rereading your comment, I’m starting to understand. However, another puzzling phenomenon occurred. When adding code like console.log("This is a dead code."); inside if (flag) { ... } , this console.log was excluded from the bundle as dead code. Why did this happen (while the module itself is bundled)? Is this a process separate from the Tree Shaker?

I assume, these details aren't documented. The only way to find out, why this happens, is to read the source code
